# How to get rid from ?callback=myCallback&_=1340513330866?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to capture data from an HTML page that is on the another website. I need to capture that data and save it into my site. That's why I used cross domain ajax like this

```
var myCallback = function(data) {
    console.log(data);
};
var formData = $('.data-capture-form').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://prospectbank.co.uk/leads/capt',
    type: 'GET',
    data: formData,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'myCallback'
}).done(function(res) {
    console.log(res);
}).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
});
```

Then I get this error
[image]

Any help? Thanks

Comment: It seems like you didn't define the function "myCallback"

Comment: I defined that already. But same error.. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The response from http://prospectbank.co.uk/leads/capt?_=1340513330866? is wrong formatted JSON.

```
{"status":true}
```

It should be

```
{status:true}
```